# How to assign different colours to different categories of data in R

Tags: r

I've only just started with R and we've been asked to do some simple statistical analysis on the iris data set. One of the questions was to plot a scatter of Sepal length against Sepal width and see if there is a trend. This is what I've got:

```
plot(iris[,1], iris[,2]) # Scatter Plot of the 1st and 2nd Columns
lines(lowess(iris[,1], iris[,2]), col = "red") # No apparent Correlation
```

The question then goes on to say, use a different colour for each category, ie the one for the Sepal length and one for the Sepal width. I was thinking about something like this, but it's obviously wrong:

```
c == col("blue", "green")
plot(iris[,1], iris[,2], col = c) # Scatter Plot of the 1st and 2nd Columns
lines(lowess(iris[,1], iris[,2]), col = "red") # No apparent Correlation
```

This is probably very simple but nothing I've tried seems to work. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You can use `plot(iris[,1], iris[,2], col = iris[,5])` to produce a scatterplot with different colors depending on the Species.

Answer (score 1):

Or you can simply do that

```
data(iris)
require(ggplot2)
qplot(Sepal.Length, Petal.Length, data = iris, color = Species)
```

The code will generate the chart below
[image: ggplot example]